# SQL inserted - deleted Tables

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-update

I want to update a table and get the updated records from default "inserted" table of SQL Server.

Updating part of the following query is successful but why does the remaining "    SELECT * FROM inserted" part of the query raise error as "Invalid object name 'inserted'."?

```
use AdventureWorks
go

UPDATE TOP(50) Person.Address
SET  City= 'PARIS'

SELECT * FROM inserted
```

Comment: As stand-alone items, `inserted` and `deleted` can only be used within triggers.  It appears that you want the list of records that were affected by the `update`?  In that case, you'll need to use the `output` clause as SqlACID suggests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would want to do this:

```
 UPDATE TOP(50) Person.Address set
 city='Paris' output inserted.*
```

unless you want the old value, in which case use deleted.*

Comment: or `output inserted.*`, etc. to get all columns from the affected rows.

Comment: It raises error: "Msg 334, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The target table 'Person.Address' of the DML statement cannot have any enabled triggers if the statement contains an OUTPUT clause without INTO clause."

Comment: @Ahmet Altun - You have to create a table variable that captures the output and then you query that table after the update statment. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2008/07/11/update-with-output-clause-triggers-and-sqlmoreresults.aspx